# Android switch bind text

Tags: android, binding, mvvmcross

Is it possible to bind the text property of a [switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) control?

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the inheritance tree - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html - a `Switch` **is a** `TextView` - so any binding like `Text` which works on `TextView` should work on `Switch`

Comment: I/MvxBind (8253):  30,80 View type not found - Switch
MvxBind:Error: 30,80 View type not found - Switch

Comment: Well... you have my answer... yes you can bind it, beyond that, it's your error to hunt :/